# You can see me in different face

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I can be a tiny fruit - if you collect enough of me, you can turn me into something you like.

I can also be a gigantic creature cut into 6 pieces. Two of them are tiny.

Finally, I can also be eccentric creature that can understand any language - in this form, I have a strange feature shared with Kēlen.

Who am I?

Hint 1:

> Generally, puzzles are inspired from the creator's background

Hint 2:

> I'm an Indonesian

Hint 3:

> The three possibility is a different thing of same name, hence [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay).

Hint 4:

> This word (one of the possibility) has an intimate relationship with Indonesia

Comment: there is no language similar to kelen. by definition

Comment: @njzk2 What do you mean

Comment: kelen is a language designed to be similar to no existing (human) language. It was built *for* that.

Comment: @njzk2 it is `creature` not `human`

Comment: but kelen is an original creation based on basically nothing. it is not similar to any languages, human or otherwise.

Comment: @njzk2  wikipedia says ..."Kēlen also comes with its own writing system, which bears a superficial resemblance to Devanagari."

Comment: @ChristianIrwan Is the creature living?

Comment: @Ruslan It doesn't matter.

Comment: `language with strange feature shared with Kēlen`, I guess it is a language with no verbs. Since the creature is not human, and it can understand a language, I think it is a kind of animal or a computer.

Comment: Is the creature based on some fictional work, or similar to a character in such fiction?

Comment: @cst1992 Ok-ok. The creature is just metaphor,

Comment: Are the grammar errors clues or just typos?

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker. The grammar errors is all typos, or maybe a clue of my background.

Comment: @njzk2 A language being designed to lack *a* feature common to existing languages does not mean it has *no* features in common with existing languages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Java

One possibility is a tiny fruit that if you collect enough of me, someone can turn me into something that you like

> Coffee beans are the the seeds of the fruit of coffee plants, and when you collect enough, you can roast, grind, and brew them into coffee.  The island of Java is so known for its Java coffee beans, that in some cases java and coffee are viewed as interchangeable.  Coffee is something that many people like.

Another possibility is a gigantic creature that is cut into 6 pieces. Two of them are tiny.

> This refers to the Indonesian island of Java, which is the world's most populous island, and which is split into four provinces and two special regions, with the provinces being larger than the special areas.

Yet another possibility is an eccentric creature which can understand any language with a strange feature shared with Kēlen (I'm not human).

> This refers to the Java programming language that many use for computer applications the world round.  I am not as familiar with the subject, but this may tie in with the title with JavaServer Faces, which used to build user interface in web applications.  **EDIT**: Per the OP in the comments, Java is a *noun-oriented language.*

Who am I?

> Intimately connected to Indonesia, coffee, and code (and the OP), you are **JAVA**.

Comment: oh my god, this has to be it

Comment: @question_asker I'd be at a loss if it were anything else.  After finally breaking my nonsensical reluctance to do some research on Indonesia, it all started to make sense.  The third usage definitely threw me for a bit of a loop, though.  And I had thought about cocoa for the first one for *so long*, getting nowhere, only to come back to something very similar.

Comment: I was trying to think of berries (that you'd put into a pie, maybe?) but nothing came, and when he said it definitely wasn't Dragon (and acted like that was the worst possible guess) that destroyed that possibility, too

Comment: "This is a good guess, but it's not what I was thinking of!  Please look at the clues harder and guess again" -- OP

Comment: Java is noun-oriented.

Comment: @ChristianIrwan Ah, I got it.  Nice job having three distinct definitions.  This was a nice, fun puzzle once I actually rolled my sleeves up and got to work on it.

Answer (score 7):

This is a completely wild guess bordering the realm of absurdity, but - I'll still put it out there!

> Atom (or perhaps a molecule, quark, or something physics-related)

One possibility is a tiny fruit that if you collect me enough, someone can turn me into something that you like

> Atoms/molecules are the building blocks of everything

Another possibility is a gigantic creature that is cut into 6 pieces. Two of them is tiny.

> Depending on what you mean by "pieces", you can find 6 properties in an atom (electrons, isotopes, neutrons, protons -> the latter two consisting of quarks and gluons - which are very tiny). In comparison to these particles, the actual atom is gigantic.

Yet another possibility is a eccentric creature can understand language with strange feature shared with Kēlen (I'm not human).

> I'm going to go on a massive limb here. The only thing Kelen shares with any other language is the Devanagari writing system, which is a script for many languages - one of them being Sanskrit. *In some philosophies/theories*, Sanskrit is considered the building block of most of the world's other languages, as atoms are the building block of all that's physical.

Comment: Sorry, it's not right.

Comment: I think you are confused about 'isotope'; an isotope is another differently structured atom of the same element.. not a 'piece' of an atom. From googling 'define isotope': ..each of two or more forms of the same element that contain equal numbers of protons but different numbers of neutrons in their nuclei, and hence differ in relative atomic mass but not in chemical properties; in particular, a radioactive form of an element..

Answer (score 5):

Hm, i have a wild guess, but i can not really backup it with facts:

Is the Answer:

> a Dragon
>
>  there is a dragon fruit in asia, dont know much about it, but maybe this is meant by the tiny fruit
>
>  I remember a myth about a giant dragon, which created some island when dying and falling into the sea. But i can not remember where i heard that myth, but i think it was about an asian country...
>
>  Dragons in myths are known to speak all languages...

Comment: No, it's wrong. And it doesn't even deserve upvote.

Comment: @ChristianIrwan it's not the right answer, and obviously not worked out to the desired degree, but it's a completely valid guess that fits the clues quite well, saying it doesn't deserve upvotes is just ridiculous

Comment: @DrunkWolf I'm glad I'm not the only person who had this reaction

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> kiwi

One possibility is a tiny fruit that if you collect enough of me, someone can turn me into something that you like

> kiwifruit is somewhat small

Another possibility is a gigantic creature that is cut into 6 pieces. Two of them are tiny.

> kiwi currency - Historically, there were six different coins: 1c, 2c, 5c, 10c, 20c, and 50c

Yet another possibility is an eccentric creature which can understand any language with a strange feature shared with Kēlen (I'm not human).

> Well, this doesn't fit, because kiwi birds are not human but can't understand verbless languages, and Kiwis are human and may or may not understand verbless languages.

Relevance:

> Indonesia is one of the closest countries to NZ (even though still 7500 km away)